# Python Pmw EntryField background colour properties

Tags: python, tkinter, pmw

I have a GUI using the Pmw library  and the background of the root is blue. When the widget is placed on the blue background the grey original colour of the widget shows over the blue background. I managed to remove this by changing `label_bg` property of the label part of the `EntryField` but **not** the Entry box part to the right of the label.

```
self.StudentID=Pmw.EntryField(self.StudentTab, label_font=("verdana", 12, "bold"),
                              labelpos="w", label_text="Student ID",
                              entry_width=3, label_bg="blue", label_fg="yellow",
                              entry_bg="blue",
                              validate={"validator":"real", "min":1, "max":150 })
                              #validation for the student id (bigger than 1
                              #and smaller than 150)
    self.StudentID.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=30, pady=10)
```

You can see in the code above a sample of the code for a typical `EntryField`. The `label_bg="blue"` changes the background of the label part of the component.

1. Either: how do I access the full list of attributes in an `EntryField`?
2. Or: Does anyone know the equivalent attribute for the textbox colour?
3. I have tried `entry_bg="Blue"` but although this did not give an error it did not change anything.
4. Could it be I need to change the background colour of the hull component, if so how?

Comment: The Entry box you talk about is probably a standard `Tkinter.Text` widget which has many "attributes" or options of its own. There's some documentation [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html). You can probably read the source the `pmw` module and find where it creates the Entry box/`Tkinter.Text` part of an `EntryField` and see what it does and whether or not you can change it by passing in an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was the last option which was to change the hull_background property. It seems that by trial and error it was the only option left and seems to solve it.